# Deduplicating dataframe causes issues with splitting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function to split a dataset into training and test sets:

```
def train_test_split(df, train_percent=.7, seed=None):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    perm = np.random.permutation(df.index)
    m = len(df.index)
    train_end = int(train_percent * m)
    train = df.iloc[perm[:train_end]]
    test = df.iloc[perm[train_end:]]
    return train, test
```

It works fine on a dataframe that is `249681 rows × 9 columns`

Of these, I decided to drop 4 columns because of too many missing values:

```
df_subset_dup = df_encode.iloc[:,:5]
df_subset = df_subset_dup.drop_duplicates()
```

After that, when I do `df_trainRaw4, df_testRaw4 = train_test_split(df_subset)`, I get `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`. However, doing `df_trainRaw4, df_testRaw4 = train_test_split(df_subset_dup)` returns no errors.

What am I doing with `drop_duplicates` that's causing the error and how do I rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `perm` is the data frame's actual index, but you are using position based `iloc` to subset the data frame with `perm`; This could be an issue after dropping duplicates which removes some index and now your largest index is larger than the number of rows of the data frame; Changing `iloc` to `loc` should fix it:

```
train = df.loc[perm[:train_end]]
test = df.loc[perm[train_end:]]
```